# Execute function on app controller from today widget button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I need to execute a function (that basically start updating location and distance driven) without opening any view controller (on background)

I need the widget to work like a "remote control" of a button inside my app.

Then when I open the app, the process should be running and showing the respective view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can't communicate directly with your app's process. If you don't want to launch the app immediately, you can just pass it some data via your shared container:

```
let sharedUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mycompany.myapp")!
sharedUserDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "tracking location")
sharedUserDefaults.synchronize()
```

Then in your app's `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, you can read that value out:

```
let sharedUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.mycompany.myapp")!
if sharedUserDefaults.boolForKey("tracking location") {
    startTrackingLocation()
}
sharedUserDefaults.removeObjectForKey("tracking location")
sharedUserDefaults.synchronize()
```

Your today widget controller can also be a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and track the user's location while the widget is visible.

Comment: That's the problem, the widget will be visible just for a couple of seconds, just to hit "play", it need to be catching data a lot of time... Then, when the user finish the process, he can review all data on app. Isn't possible to run an app without showing it to user?